# Can't install Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 4. The command "ubuntu-device-flash" hangs

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I followed all of the steps here:
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

and all steps worked fine up until this:

```
hmusr@hmusr:~$ ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap
2015/11/15 18:10:21 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2015/11/15 18:10:21 Device is |mako|
2015/11/15 18:10:21 Flashing version 24 from ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device mako
6.29 MB / 6.29 MB [==========================================] 100.00 % 330.51 KB/s 
52.45 MB / 52.45 MB [========================================] 100.00 % 438.29 KB/s 
278.21 MB / 278.21 MB [======================================] 100.00 % 667.55 KB/s 
/home/hmusr/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu/mako/version-24.tar.xz
/home/hmusr/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz
/home/hmusr/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz
/home/hmusr/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/custom-9282f1b27ad6e4c1118551162ef9f9165549ee6ab118c7461d2dcea0a39dc47e.tar.xz
/home/hmusr/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-d16c1032d25d5ebfb02511d6c4513ec0582b0c8f20710128ad53369368d2e28e.tar.xz
2015/11/15 18:17:46 Start pushing /home/hmusr/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu/mako/version-24.tar.xz to device
2015/11/15 18:17:46 Start pushing /home/hmusr/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2015/11/15 18:17:46 Start pushing /home/hmusr/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2015/11/15 18:17:46 Start pushing /home/hmusr/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/custom-9282f1b27ad6e4c1118551162ef9f9165549ee6ab118c7461d2dcea0a39dc47e.tar.xz to device
2015/11/15 18:17:46 Start pushing /home/hmusr/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-d16c1032d25d5ebfb02511d6c4513ec0582b0c8f20710128ad53369368d2e28e.tar.xz to device
2015/11/15 18:17:46 Start pushing /home/hmusr/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/ubuntu-933cfeb2df2c7937de7ed334797c33977f1dced25c732e98b367ed7fedce43da.tar.xz to device
2015/11/15 18:18:12 Done pushing /home/hmusr/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu/mako/version-24.tar.xz to device
2015/11/15 18:18:12 Done pushing /home/hmusr/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2015/11/15 18:18:12 Done pushing /home/hmusr/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
```

The last line shown above has been there for over 12 hours with nothing further.  Not sure how to proceed.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You could try cleaningthe local cache bythis command: 'ubuntu-device-flash --cleanup-cache touch'.

After that just rerun your flash command.

If its NOT the first time your flashing UbuntuTouch? Then try it without the '--bootstrap' option.